# Нахождение одинакового слова в разных тегах HTML с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть определенный текст, который состоит из отдельных тегов `<p>`

```
<div class="content">
<p>Нужный текст с названием "name"</p>
<p>Ненужный текст</p>
<p>Нужный текст с названием "name"</p>
<p>Ненужный текст</p>
<p>Нужный текст с названием "name"</p>
</div>
```

Мне необходимо заменить все слова **"name"** на **"имя"**

Для этого я нахожу каждый `<p>`, в котором содержится нужное мне слово с помощью jQuery:

```
var content = $(".content")
    string  = content.find('p:contains("name")')
```

После этого я заменяю слово таким образом:

```
string.text(string.text().replace("name", "имя"))
```

На выходе получается замена всех **"name"** на содержимое переменной `string`, в которой лежит весь текст(ниже содержимое переменной)

> Нужный текст с названием "имя"Нужный текст с названием "name"Нужный текст с названием "name"

Ответа в интернете не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь к знатокам. Заранее спасибо

P.S Пробовал обработать циклом, там еще хуже варианты получаются

Comment: `[...$('p')].forEach((e)=>{e.innerHTML=e.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("name","g"), "Имя")})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подход переделан, там образом, что если внутри `<p>` будут HTML теги, то он обработает и их, при этом не затронет значения атрибутов, которые схожи с поиском (последний `<p>` в качестве примера).

Описание по коду внутри комментариями пометил.

```js
var reg = new RegExp('(?<!\=)\"(name)\"(?!\>)', 'gim'); // регулярка

$('.content > p').each(function() { // Проходим по всем элементам
  var html = $(this).html(); // берём HTML элемента
  if(reg.test(html)) { // Проверяем есть ли наличие совпадения по регулярке
    $(this).html(html.replace(reg, '\"имя\"')); // Заменяем текст на нужный
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>Нужный текст с названием "name"</p>
  <p>Ненужный текст</p>
  <p>Нужный текст с названием "name"</p>
  <p>Ненужный текст</p>
  <p>
    <span name="name" style="color: red">Нужный текст с названием "name"</span>
  </p>
</div>
```